# how to count the last character in a text file in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I have a text file. I want to Count the last names ending with "E". This is the code I have so far. I know it is not correct but I am stuck and do not know what else to do to make it work.

```
def ans9(file):
    infile = open(file)
    contents = infile.read().split()
    infile.close()
    return len(contents)
    ans9.reverse()
    for word in ans9: 
        print(word[e])
```

Comment: The `return` statement preceding `len(contents)` will exit the function before any of your other code runs.

Comment: Also, try out a content manager for opening/closing files; they make things easier for us! --> https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the file, the name and the float number are delimited by `tab`. What you want to do is open a file, read it line by line. Then go through those lines (one line at a time), split it on `tab` character (`\t`) and take the first element of that list (name) and then a last character of that name. In code, it would look like this:

```
with open(file, ‘r’) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

cnt = 0
for i in lines:
    if i.split(‘\t’)[0][-1] == ‘e’ or i.split(‘\t’)[0][-1] == ‘E’:
          cnt += 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I was typing that on my phone. I've added the description now.